# Spring Security 6, Angular 13 CORS problem OPTIONS request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, cors

i have this application in Springboot for the backend and the angular app as frontend my problem is that when i perform a http get call from angular to the backend it response me with a

'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/operator/getall' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

to understand more here some pics of my backend and fronted project of the interceptor and all security configuration stuff

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                        .permitAll().requestMatchers("/operator/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(
                        jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config)
            throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/operator")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public class OperatoreController {

    @Autowired
    private OperatoreService operatoreService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/getall")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Operatore>> getAllOperatore(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(operatoreService.getAll());
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/auth")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private OperatoreService operatoreService;

    @Autowired
    private final AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtAuthenticationResponse> Login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.signin(request));
    }
}
```

the frontend service that performs the call

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll() {
    console.log(`${environment.apiUrl}/${environment.servizi.api.getAll}`)
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/${environment.servizi.api.getAll}`)
  }

}
```

the interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {

      console.log("SEEET token "+ currentUser.token)
      /**request = request.clone({
       headers: request.headers.append("Authorization",`Bearer ${currentUser.token}`)
       });**/
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

the weirder things is that only on that method in OperatoreController getall does return this error, the authentication works and it return the jwt as expected

[!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzBXk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzBXk.png)

and trying on postman and works too

[!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsM7B.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsM7B.png)

**JwtAuthenticationFilter**

```
@Component
```

@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
private final JwtServiceImpl jwtService;
private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
private final UserDetail userService;
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String userEmail;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !StringUtils.startsWith(authHeader, "Bearer ")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
    userEmail = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userEmail)
            && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userService.userDetailService()
                .loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
        var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                .map(t -> !t.isExpired() && !t.isRevoked())
                .orElse(false);
        if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid && userDetails.isEnabled()) {
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            context.setAuthentication(authToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

**EDIT 1**

after a some modifications i do to my code i figure out that Angular makes a OPTIONS request but to access to request method in /operator/getAll it must to be Authenticated so my JwtAuthenticationFilter discard it and then the CorsError appers infact if we try to move the method in the AuthenticationController that doesnt need the JWT  accept the request

[image]

[image]

but i cant add the jwt to OPTIONS request for the CORS policy and i want that to acces to OperatorController the request must be authenticathed so i dont know how to figure out with this problem can someone help me

Comment: Is the slash @RequestMapping(path = "operator/") on the right side?

Comment: don't think you can set origins to wild-card ("*") when using credentials.

Comment: Angular doesn't send an OPTIONS request... the browser does.   When preflight is triggered, the browser asks the server "hey, do you allow cross site requests from this origin using this method with credentials?"... and the server responds... then your Angular call goes through, or not.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request  The browser restricts cross-origin calls in this way.  Also be aware that Postman doesn't restrict cross-origin requests or send preflight requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a proxy configuration for it to work. I suspect what you tried was not correct maybe?

For Production, you need to configure your server to serve the app from the same url, or orchestrate your apps with reverse-proxies etc.

For the development server to work, you can use the built-in proxy of the Angular CLI.

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

1. Create `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

(the pathRewrite is up to you, I belive you don't need that at the moment, but it would be wise to dedicate an url segment for backend calls)

2. add this to `angular.json` under the `projects/<your projectname>/architect/serve`:

```
"options": {
  "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
}
```

and now `ng serve` should work.

Comment: Such a proxy can only be a temporary fix (only viable during development), though. What is the OP to do when the time comes to release to production?

Comment: set up an internal reverse-proxy, or host the app from the same domain.

Comment: i made an edit to question i alredy try the solutions that you comment